# Accessing DOM Elements in JavaScript Tests

Tags: javascript, dom, karma-jasmine

We are currently writing JavaScript tests in karma/jasmine for our Grails/Groovy based project. Our JavaScript code requires access to DOM elements created and defined in gsp pages. We are unsure of how to access these DOM elements in our JavaScript test files. It would be great to get an opinion from some one who has already worked in this.

Comment: Is it an angularjs application or what ?

Comment: It is a Grails/Groovy based web application and in our Javascript tests we are facing problem in accessing DOM elements used by that JavaScript code.